# Clear password field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<input name="e_password" id="e_password" type="password" autocomplete="off" />
```

The above is a password field which for some reason, is automatically filled **only in Mozilla (not in Chrome and IE11)**. Obviously it keeps the value field from previous trials. I tried so much to clear this field. The **only** way I can manage it, is through the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){      
  $('input:text').val(''); 
});
```

Unfortunately, the above resets all the other text fields inside the form which is undesirable. Also,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:password').val('');
});
```

does not work!
Moreover, I tried this:

```
<div class="abc">   
   <input name="e_password" id="e_password" type="password" autocomplete="off" />
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.abc input:text').val('');    
});
```

Nor, this works...
Of course, I tried the obvious:

```
$('#e_password').val('');
```

which also did not work.
I repeat that the problem exists only in Mozilla. What else may I do?

Thank you

Comment: It is unbelievable;however, none of the following proposed solutions works! Of course it is a matter of Mozilla passwords and I want to overcome it with code. For the moment it seems impossible.

Comment: I cannot still understand why the only thing that works is $('input:text').val(''); and how to make it το affect only "e_password"...

Comment: One more detail. If trying to assign something different from "", e.g. $('#e_password').val('12q'); everything works fine!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it!!

```
setTimeout(function(){ $('#e_password').val('');}, 50);
```

Hopefully, the above works. However, I cannot give a satisfactory explanation why this small delay solves the problem...Most probably, it is a Mozilla bug.

Comment: the new coorect answer is "autocomplete="new-password" provided by @Vitalicus

Answer (score 5):

```
document.getElementById("e_password").value = "";
```

or

```
$('input[type="password"]#e_password').val('');
```

Comment: that didn't work in Mozilla, the only way is to delay. I think the autocomplete feature of Firefox works even after the document is ready

Answer (score 2):

Chrome ignore `autocomplete="off"`

Use `autocomplete="new-password"` in input

```
<input type="password" autocomplete="new-password">
```

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=587466

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer. See also: [The autocomplete attribute and login fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#the_autocomplete_attribute_and_login_fields). It is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

$("#e_password").val('') works for me in firefox. Can you try with this ?

```
$("#e_password").attr("value","")
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('e_password').value = '';
```

Or using jQuery:

```
$('#e_password').attr('value','');
```

Answer (score 0):

`autocomplete="off"` must be set for `form` element not `input`

```
<form autocomplete="off">
    ....
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but I guess it is not a code problem at all !!. It may be the saved passwords in the browser. For example when you open up the page in chrome , just check out the top right of the omnibox and you can click the cross to delete the saved password for that page. I guessed this because you say it comes only in mozilla and not other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I did it a way that is not mentioned yet. This was after trying almost all suggestions in this thread (except the timeout as I don't want to add any unnecessary delays in my page).

The problem I saw was when the browser autofilled the password field, the value is not being set. So

```
$('#password').val("");
```

will not work, because the value is already "".

So I did it in 2 lines.

```
$('#password').val("a");
$('#password').val("");
```

I set the value to something so I could clear it out. Then the browser autofill field is cleared.

Hope this helps someone out there!

Answer (score 0):

FF is using "change" event when auto-filling (at least in v51).

try something like

```
// if your input is in html
$(document).ready(function(){ 

/* // if you create input from code like this
$("body").html('<input class="password" type="password" id="e_password">').promise().done(function(){
*/

   $("#e_password").on("change", function() { //append this event
         $("#e_password").off("change"); //optional, depends on your code
         $("#e_password").val(''); //clear
         $("#e_password").attr("value",""); //clear #2 (just to be sure)
    });  

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome ignore `autocomplete="off"`

Use `autocomplete="new-password"` in input